# what are the pros and cons of using a lambda converted from express vs using a raw lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, serverless

I am doing a research to understand what the pros and cons would be to convert an express app to lambda vs using a raw lambda.

is any faster, more resilient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general they are going to be pretty much the same. Using the express framework or any other lambda friendly framework will add some overhead but it should be negligible imo (not tested but express is pretty small and fast). What you really get is the potential benefit of routing and/or being able to take an existing piece of express code and moving it to a lambda. That being said I am a purist and I do not do that as I prefer working with the "raw" lambda rather than abstracting things though sometimes I do find myself creating mini routers but that's not very hard. It's really a matter of preference and convenience. While you are researching there are also things that sit in between raw and express such as [middly](https://middy.js.org/) which are pretty cool. Essentially the pros of express without loading the framework.